# Read text-file with words and their occurrence count & print output sorted

Tags: grep, sort

I have a text file with the following format (retweets and username):

```
RT @username2    4
RT @Userddssdw   7
RT @usernam54    1
RT @Userddss44   1
RT @usernam1     1
RT @Userddssd1   6
```

Is there a way of sorting by occurrence and output the result like:

```
RT @Userddssdw   7
RT @Userddssd1   6
RT @username2    4
RT @usernam54    1
RT @Userddss44   1
RT @usernam1     1
```

Chris$ somethingIdontKnow | with grep | sort ./textfile.txt

Comment: Have you looked at `man sort`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sort -r -g -k3 textfile.txt
```

This will perform a general numeric, reverse `sort` of the output using the third field.  `-g` is a GNU specific option.

As mentioned by Jeff Schaller, the non-GNU specific option for a numeric `sort` follows:

```
sort -r -n -k3 textfile.txt
```

Comment: This looks like it. Only when a number of 13 or 18 exist, it will see it as an 1 And lower than 9 I think

Comment: Consider `sort -k3rn`

Comment: (`-g` being specific to GNU sort)